# Why is the WSL OpenGL version different depending on the distro?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, opengl

I'm struggling with a problem on my WSL distros. I have an Ubuntu 20.04 in which the OpenGL version is 2.1, and it won't use the hardware rendering of WSLg.  I've also installed an Ubuntu 22.04 distro, which works properly with the GPU accelerated WSLg features:

Result of `glxinfo -B` on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL vendor string: Brian Paul
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa X11
OpenGL version string: 4.5 Mesa 8.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
```

Result of `glxinfo -B` on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Microsoft Corporation (0xffffffff)
    Device: D3D12 (NVIDIA Quadro T1000) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 22.0.1
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 20212MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.3
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA Quadro T1000)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

Can someone help me or show me the way to do it?

Windows Version:

```
11 Pro
Version 21H2
Build 22000.739
```

Edit 06/24:

Result of `dpkg -l "mesa*" "libgl*"` on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version                           Architecture Description
+++-=================================-=================================-============-===========================================================
ii  libgl1:amd64                      1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
un  libgl1-amber-dri                  <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64             22.2~git2206220600.e8fc5c~oibaf~f amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
un  libgladeui-2-6                    <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64               22.2~git2206220600.e8fc5c~oibaf~f amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia             <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libgles2:amd64                    1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLESv2 support
un  libglib-object-introspection-perl <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libglib2.0-0:amd64                2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4            amd64        GLib library of C routines
ii  libglib2.0-bin                    2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4            amd64        Programs for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-data                   2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4            all          Common files for GLib library
ii  libglvnd0:amd64                   1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                22.2~git2206220600.e8fc5c~oibaf~f amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
un  libglx-vendor                     <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libglx0:amd64                     1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.2           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX support
ii  mesa-utils                        8.4.0-1build1                     amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
un  mesa-vulkan-drivers               <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
```

Result of `dpkg -l "mesa*" "libgl*"` on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                               Version           Architecture Description
+++-=================================-=================-============-============================================================
ii  libgl-dev:amd64                   1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GL development files
ii  libgl1:amd64                      1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
ii  libgl1-amber-dri:amd64            21.3.7-0ubuntu1   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64             22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64             22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
un  libgladeui-2-6                    <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64               22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia             <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libgles-dev:amd64                 1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLES development files
ii  libgles1:amd64                    1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLESv1 support
ii  libgles2:amd64                    1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLESv2 support
un  libgles2-mesa-dev                 <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libglew-dev:amd64                 2.2.0-4           amd64        OpenGL Extension Wrangler - development environment
ii  libglew2.2:amd64                  2.2.0-4           amd64        OpenGL Extension Wrangler - runtime environment
un  libglib-object-introspection-perl <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libglib2.0-0:amd64                2.72.1-1          amd64        GLib library of C routines
ii  libglib2.0-bin                    2.72.1-1          amd64        Programs for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-data                   2.72.1-1          all          Common files for GLib library
un  libglu-dev                        <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
un  libglu1                           <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                9.0.2-1           amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64            9.0.2-1           amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libglvnd-core-dev:amd64           1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- core development files
ii  libglvnd-dev:amd64                1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- development files
ii  libglvnd0:amd64                   1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library
ii  libglx-dev:amd64                  1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX development files
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
un  libglx-vendor                     <aucune>          <aucune>     (aucune description n'est disponible)
ii  libglx0:amd64                     1.4.0-1           amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX support
```

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -S $(which glxinfo)` on the older system?

Comment: Have you done a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`?  I just installed a fresh 20.04, and I get different results before and after an `upgrade`.

Comment: @yannliep - You should [edit] your question to indicate what version of Windows 11 you are running.

Comment: @user1686 results of dpkg :  `mesa-utils: /usr/bin/glxinfo`
@NotTheDr01ds yes I've done the update and upgrade.

Comment: Could you add `dpkg -l "mesa*" "libgl*"` into the post?

Comment: @user1686 I've edited the post

Comment: Any news? I need this too...